# Сравнение дат

Tags: php, сравнение, дата

Насколько коректно  сравнивать даты таким образом?

```
$today = date('Y-m-d'); 
$outdate = "2011-11-02";

if($today >= $outdate) {...
```

Раньше знаю надо было переводить в разные таймштампы, но похоже сейчас, если задать дату именно в таком формате. все должно быть ок, разве не так?

Comment: Врядли потому что в таком случае вы сравниваете строки.

Comment: @AlexWindHope
Неправда! Сравните это  
    `$curdate = date('d.m.Y', strtotime('now')); $revenge_date = "25.05.2015";`  
если будут первые числа месяца, то они будет меньше 25, хоть и год будет больше. И код будет работать неправильно!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Если обе даты точно в формате `Y-m-d` (или `Y-m-d H:i:s`), то логично сравнивать их как строки, т.е.

```
$date1='2011-02-12';
$date2='2012-02-13';
$result=($date1<$date2); //$result === true
```

Но если нет уверенности, что формат дат одинаковый, то лучше привести их к формату unixtime и сравнивать как числа:

```
$date1='2011-02-12';
$date2='13.02.2012';
$result=($date1<$date2); //$result === false
$result=(strtotime($date1)<strtotime($date2)); //$result === true
```

Comment: Ну практически то же что и я написал только в коде, согласен

Comment: > Если даты точно в одном формате, то логично сравнивать их как строки, т.е.

Это не совсем так. Что бы сравнение строк работало корректно, нужно не только, что бы формат совпадал, но и что бы этот формат соответствовал стандарту [ISO 8601](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), по которому дата записывается по убыванию значимости. 

Т.е. вариант `date('d.m.Y') >= '02.11.2011'` уже работать не будет, хоть формат и совпадает.

Comment: вообщето лучше сравнивать функцией strcmp

но скорей всего она и вызывается, неявно

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [strtotime](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php), т.е. переведите ваши строки, которые вы получаете через date в метку времени unix, т.е. в число int и тогда удобно можно сравнить

Comment: А разницы? в данном случае ее попросту нет...

Comment: Как это нет??

Comment: действительно, как это нет? сравнивать строки и числа нет разницы? сделай этот пример сам и увидишь)

Comment: @Barton, @Dem объясните плз разницу сравнения строк и чисел, когда не нужна разность между датами?

Comment: Вообщем то если целые числа хранятся как строки, то тогда разницы нет, а вот с float в строках уже придется поиграться. В данном случае, @Loric правильно написал. но нам то откуда известно что даты будут всегда в одном формате? поэтому и прибегаем к использованию ф-ии перевода в int

Comment: ТС указал в задании что даты в одном формате, @Barton вы спалились как ни крути. Вы просто так пафостно и уверено написали <br>]
"сделай этот пример сам и увидишь)" что после этого уже никак не отвертитесь :)

Comment: Чесно говоря мне наплевать, я предложил универсальное решение и как никрути оно работает. Кого обидел - звиняйте)

Comment: Так вы скопируйте пример, приведите 2 такие даты в одном формате, чтобы пример не работал и объясните, почему это неверно. Универсалов понапоявлялось)

Answer (score 1):

Сравнивать как строки даты нельзя не в коем случае, это будет не корректно в случае если у вас:

```
$date1 = '01.03.1956';
$date2 = '05.06.1930';
```

Выражение `$date2 > $date1 ? true : false;` Вернет `true` по той причине, что строки сравниваются посимвольно, соответственно поскольку 5 > 1, строка `$date2 > $date1`.

Конечно формат `2011-02-12` вернет корректное сравнение, но это потенциально опасный код.