# Сортировка массива по дате php

Tags: php, массивы, json, arraylist

Есть массив формата

```
     Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
      [date] => 01.09.2016
      [sum] => 450
  )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [date] => 31.08.2016
            [sum] => 156
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [date] => 02.09.2016
            [sum] => 888
        )

        [3] => Array
        (
            [date] => 02.09.2016
            [sum] => 388
        )
        [4] => Array
        (
            [date] => 02.09.2016
            [sum] => 488
        )
        [5] => Array
        (
            [date] => 02.09.2016
            [sum] => 858
        )
        [6] => Array
        (
            [date] => 02.12.2016
            [sum] => 450
        )
)
```

Как я могу его отсортировать по датам и для каждой даты сделать массив с ключем даты и записать количество заказов в этот день,  например для 02.09.2016

```
[02.09.2016] => Array
            (
                [count] => 4 /*Количество массивов с одинаковой датой***/

            )
```

И так для всех дат в массиве

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сравнение дат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/39104/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82)

Comment: @VerNick а с чего вы взяли что это дубликат? и указали ссылку, там другой вопрос, здесь вообще то другой.. Дублирующее только слово "Дата" ))

Comment: @Arsen Этот вопрос про сортировку дат, следовательно сравнение.

Comment: Странная логика )) сравнение двух дат и сортировка массива по дате - это вообще разные вещи ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете сделать так:

```
    <?php
    $data = array();
    $array = array(

        array(
            'date' => '05.09.2016',
            'sum' => 470,
        ),
        array(
            'date' => '11.11.2016',
            'sum' => 470,
        ),
        array(
            'date' => '05.09.2016',
            'sum' => 100,
        ),
        array(
            'date' => '01.09.2016',
            'sum' => 490,
        ),
        array(
            'date' => '10.10.2016',
            'sum' => 550,
        ),


    );

    foreach ( $array as $row ) {

        $key = $row[ 'date' ];
        $val = $row[ 'sum' ];

        if ( array_key_exists( $key, $data ) ) {
            $data[ $key ] += $val;
        } else {
            $data[ $key ] = $val;
        }


    }

    ksort( $data );

    print_r( $data );
/*
Array
(
    [01.09.2016] => 490
    [05.09.2016] => 570
    [10.10.2016] => 550
    [11.11.2016] => 470
)

*/
```

Но я бы посоветовал сравнивать даты в UNIX формате, для этого надо не полениться и сделать ещё пару `for` ))

Comment: еще бы их не сравнивать в юникс формате, у вас без этого `01.12.2018` будет стоять раньше чем `12.01.2018`

Comment: @teran полность согласен, я сам ярый противник строковых сравнений дат, мой пример больше простая логика переборов. Заметил одно обсуждение   [ТЫК](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/39104/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82) там столько плюсовали некорректный ответ, я был в шоке )) думал за последний год что то новое пропустил в PHP ))

Comment: там вполне нормальный ответ заплюсован. Если дата записана в виде `y.m.d.` то ее можно сортировать как строки. здесь же формат `d.m.Y` что в корне меняет проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Если вас интересует только количество заказов,  то для этих целей есть функция `array_count_values`, останется отсортировать результат по ключам, переведя их в даты из строк.

```
$result = array_count_values(array_column($data, 'date'));
uksort($result, function($a,$b){ return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);});
print_r($result);
```

Можно также изначально даты перевести к меткам времени, а потом подсчитать. Тогда достаточно будет обычной сортировки по ключам.

```
$result = array_count_values(array_map("strtotime", array_column($data, 'date')));
ksort($result);
```

а метки уже потом преобразовать к виду строковых да при необходимости.

Возможно, если массив получен из БД, вам вообще  стоит сделать всю работу на уровне СУБД: `select date, count(*) from data order by date` ?